# loop in twitter api laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, twitter

I'm trying to get all likes by auth user.
first I get user favorite_count.
then I start looping .
at the end I get id_str from last item in loop to get new collections. 
is it right way ?
I'm getting error '[88] Rate limit exceeded'

this is my code

```
$fav =  Twitter::getUserTimeline(['count' => 1, 'format' => 'array']);
    $count = $fav[0]['user']['favourites_count'];
    $tweets =  Twitter::getFavorites(['screen_name' => 'test', 'count' => 200 , 'format' => 'array']);

    for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
        echo $tweets[$i]['text'];
        echo '</br>';
        $end = end($tweets);
        $val = $end['id_str'];
        $tweets = Twitter::getFavorites(['screen_name' => 'test', 'count' => 200 ,'max_id' => $val, 'format' => 'array']);
    }
```

*fav_count = 1136

Comment: If fav count is 1136, you're currently bombarding the the Twitter API with 1136 requests in a row (once per iteration). Do you really need to fetch all of them?

Comment: yes,it is a must

Comment: You should read up on Twitters rate limits. You won't be able to make that many requests in such a short time.

Comment: still I need another way either by rest api or twitter streaming api

Comment: Read their docs and see what they say about rate limits etc on those. There simply are limitations on what you can do with their API's.

Answer (score 0):

Before I proceed, I think there is a logical error in the way you are using the iteration. 
Regarding the rate limited error, you could set up some kind of a queue where you execute the favorites fetching script at a specific time. Once the script has run and encountered the rate limit, read the x_header values from the response to get to know when you can make a call again to the end point. Once you have this set up a call at that time.

FYI for 1136 tweets, you would need only 6 calls to the endpoint (fetching 200 in each iteration). 
You should run a do... while loop for calling the favorites end point and within that use another loop to process the returned tweets.

Beware, twitter may not return all 200 tweets per call.